# How to export to AAC audio from Audacity?

Tags: audacity, aac

Exporting to MP3 audio from Audacity works fine, but exporting to "M4A (AAC)" results in nothing. No file is created or whatsoever.

I can see that it depends on "ffmpeg" library to work, but the application WinFF (which also makes use of this library) is working fine to me. Do I need to install anything else?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue between ffmpeg and Audacity 1.3.x

Read more about it [here](http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=FAQ%3aInstallation_and_Plug-Ins#Linux.2FUnix_2).

My guess is that the Ubuntu packagers decided not to compile Audacity with support for the ffmpeg libraries because of these issues. I don't know what versions are in the official repo, as I'm using the Getdeb.net ones. I can confirm that what you said does not work for me either, but it applies to all ffmpeg exports.